# Cannot open Cyrillic password protected xslx file with WorkBook factory

Tags: java, apache-poi, cyrillic

Trying to open an excel file with a password "абв" throws Exception saying the password is incorrect, although I've set the password myself. Opening a different file with the password "abc" is fine;

I checked if the password is encoded correctly by printing the string to a file and works fine.

```
WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("src//main//resources//Unicode.xlsx"), "абв");
```

results in

```
org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException: Password incorrect
        at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentFactoryHelper.getDecryptedStream(DocumentFactoryHelper.java:88)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:126)
```

I tried using decryptor.verifyPassword() with the same result. Why won't it work with unicode?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. For me it works using `apache poi 4.1.0`. What happens if you copy the `абв` in clipboard and then paste that into the password box while encrypt with password? Maybe your key codes while typing the `абв` are not really the key codes of the Unicode characters because of using a special keyboard layout and a special Cyrillic font different from Unicode?

Comment: @AxelRichter I copied the same абв into both the password param in the code and the password box in excel. It worked in excel, but the exception is still there. Same poi version too.

Comment: How are you compiling your Java code? My hunch is that you have the wrong encoding set

Comment: @Gagravarr i managed to get it to work by using escape sequences. I used gradle to compile

Comment: try unicode desctiption instead like u0.. whatever, imaybe your IDE or the way you launch makes the mess from reading weird symbols from . java file

Comment: You should [tell Gradle what the text encoding is of your source java files](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/06/gradle-goodness-set-java-compiler.html) then it'll work correctly without needing escapes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it to work by using escape sequences.